# What will happen to my to downloaded PDFs on springer if I no longer have institutional access?

Tags: books, springer

I'm a high schooler who self studies math. A university in my state (University of Minnesota) is offering college courses to high schoolers so I automatically get access to, and can download, books on Springer by just clicking the “access via institution” button and logging in.

I'm worried that this summer after the school year ends something will happen to my account, so I won't have access to the books.

More generally, what would happen to *anyone*'s downloaded resources after they loose access to the original website?

Comment: nothing happens to downloaded files. You can just use them forever

Comment: @Sursula holy hell

Comment: @ProPoop you want to check out this old short story: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/right-to-read.en.html

Comment: @JoshRumbut You're referring to an hypothetical situation in the future with that link. The story told there is certainly not reality today.

Comment: That's why some publishers are trying to make you read the paper throught their enhanced online reader: so you do not download it and they preserve the right to let you access (or not) them

Comment: Good question. The real question is "Do I have the right to hold a copy of a document I cannot officially access anymore?" The answer is very long, involving legalese terms and philosophical debates, or very short: "damn to the current publishing/copyright system".

Comment: @EarlGrey OP was talking about PDF's specifically. So, I don't think that, that kind of DRM is possible with PDF's or at least I have never seen them

Comment: @RemziCavdar Techincally not possible, but the real question is the legal/philosophical aspects. Having "physical" access to a document is different than having the right to access a document.

Comment: There was a case in the early times of Kindle. Some issue with the rights of a book or so. The book, bought by Kindle customers, disappeared from their Kindle - retroactively. The book was "1984" by Orwell.

Comment: @EarlGrey The legal side is easily known; OP needs to read the terms and conditions because that's the agreement OP agreed upon when OP used the service. But practically nothing will happen; OP is an individual. They don't have the manpower and resources to check every individual. That's why they come after organisations and people who have uploaded them to torrent sites and whatnot. Basically, it is either mass distribution or (huge) organisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nothing happens to downloaded files

As somebody already pointed out; nothing happens to downloaded files, you just simply lose access to Springer, so if you want to look up or download other PDF's I would suggest to do it now before you lose access.

As for the copyright and usage I would refer you to their terms and conditions. But I assume there is no real risk for anything except if you are sharing those papers online and whatnot.